# Deleting rows from a pandas Dataframe which does not match a combination of colums in another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data Frame 1 looks like:

```
   Col1 Col2 Col3
1   A    4    ab
2   A    5    de
3   A    2    ah
4   B    1    ac
5   B    3    jd
6   B    2    am
```

data frame 2:

```
  col1 col2
1  A    4
2  B    3
```

How do i delete all the rows in Data Frame 1 which do not match the combination of rows of dataframe 2?

Output Expected:

```
   Col1 Col2 Col3
1   A    4    ab
2   B    3    jd
```

Comment: inner merge on `col1` and `col2` using `df1.merge(df2,on=['col1','col2'])` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with inner join, only necessary rename columns:

```
df = df2.rename(columns={'col1':'Col1','col2':'Col2'}).merge(df1, on=['Col1','Col2'])
#on should be omited, then merge by intersection of columns of df1, df2
#df = df2.rename(columns={'col1':'Col1','col2':'Col2'}).merge(df1)

print (df)
  Col1  Col2 Col3
0    A     4   ab
1    B     3   jd
```

Another idea is use `left_on` and `right_on` parameter and then remove columns with names by `df2.columns`:

```
df = (df2.merge(df1, left_on=['col1','col2'], 
                     right_on=['Col1','Col2']).drop(df2.columns, axis=1))
print (df)
  Col1  Col2 Col3
0    A     4   ab
1    B     3   jd
```

If columns names are same:

```
print (df2)
  Col1  Col2
1    A     4
2    B     3

df = df2.merge(df1, on=['Col1','Col2'])
#df = df2.merge(df1)
print (df)
  Col1  Col2 Col3
0    A     4   ab
1    B     3   jd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use join, to do an inner join

```
dfR = df1.join( df ,on=['Col1','Col2'] ,how='inner',rsuffix='_x')
dfR[['Col1','Col2','Col3']]
```

This will also give you the same result

```
   Col1 Col2 Col3
1   A    4    ab
2   B    3    jd
```

For more details check these links [Join Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) and
[examples](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)